# Unable to find function in labview labeled "si wave"

Tags: labview

I'm in a class that has a labview course, the teacher gave us a PDF with a block diagram picture in which several icons are displayed. One of the icons is unknown to us, we are trying to find it, is it part of labview, or have you seen it before in the function libraries?

[image]

Comment: first of all, you need to rephrase your question so it uses grammatically correct English.  This is especially important for homework related questions.

Comment: ok, I was in a hurry, if I mentioned "teacher", it doesn't necessarily mean, its for homework we are doing it in class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it here:

Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2009\vi.lib\sound\lvsound.llb

it was a subvi named Snd Read Waveform.vi